# Detecting whether logged into Facebook as a page or personal profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When you log into Facebook under a personal profile for a page you manage you are able to like or unlike that page.

However when you change who you are logged in as to the actual page, there is no ability to like the page. The like button just disappears.

The signed request I get back from Facebook is similar to this

```
{
    "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
    "expires": 1368849600,
    "issued_at": 1368845302,
    "oauth_token": "CAABqdNKUvZB0BACQbcfL6Hdjb5RXYdmjUr8ZBxbqGPyfBDJwwxEtwoZCLE9nq3OZB6JTjDL53eYQmLeKzloUaySN7q9S7OZBV3NsvZBsxZBf87UIK2cC8bNH1tyZC56Xx26sreb1epUXjnxu1hS5Njdj0NnDysa8jT0ZD",
    "page": {
        "id": "2005440XXXXXXXX",
        "liked": true,
        "admin": true
    },
    "user": {
        "country": "au",
        "locale": "en_US",
        "age": {
            "min": 21
        }
    },
    "user_id": "100000XXXXXXXX"
}
```

There seems to be no way to know if they are logged in as a page or a person.

I don't need a way to bring the like button back, I just need a way to alert the user of my Facebook app to login via a personal profile instead of the page.

Comment: Just adding a thought here for me to try and review later. Getting the user_id from the signed request then querying the open graph to determine the type of object assigned to that ID.